# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js): Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization

Tags: angular, angular16

After migrating from Angular v11 to v16, getting the below error. Can I get a solution for this please.

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization

1. I have tried adding "enableIvy":false to my tsconfig.js file.
2. I have tried reinstalling the compatible typescript version.
3. Deleted the node modules and reinstalled the node.

Even after doing the above, not able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you make sure your CLI is updated as well with the most recent compatible version? Also double check the webpack you are using is compatible.

Comment: @CoreySutton

Angular CLI: 16.1.4
Node: 18.18.0
Package Manager: npm 9.8.1
Angular: 16.2.9

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.6
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.1.4
@angular/cli                    16.1.4
@angular/compiler-cli           16.0.0
@angular/http                   7.2.16
@angular/material               16.2.8
@ngtools/webpack                16.2.6
@schematics/angular             16.1.4
rxjs                            7.4.0
typescript                      5.0.4

Comment: Webpack version: -- webpack@5.88.2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.